# Connect two android apps via http REST and EJB3

Tags: android, rest, ejb-3.0

I'm writing application for android where two devices should communicate between each other via internet. In addition to this task they also communicate with the EJB3 server via REST. So I decided to kill two birds with one stone and use REST+EJB3 for transferring data between two paired android devices. 
So the scenario I implemented is something like this:

- Both devices connect to the server and acquire session id.
- First device sends data to the second device
- Server gets the data but does not end the http request, instead it puts into a waiting pool
- Second device asks for data
- Server transfers the data to the second device and releases waiting connection (and thread) for first device.
- If there are no first or second device requests then opponent waits for a timeout on a server side, then sends the request again. We need to wait for the data on the server side to give immediate respose after data is arrived.

So in this schema I see two drawbacks:
- Waiting thread on the server side - they consume server resources and as the result limit server throughput
- If the server thread will not wait for an answer with timeout, then the client should repeat requests on and on and spend a lot of traffic.

**What is the best practice solution for such problem?**

P.S: Forgot to mention that two devices should exchange data as smoothly and quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use C2DM
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

When message needs to be sent from A to B - A should connect to server and depending on data kind/amount - server will either push data via C2DM or just tell device B to come back and grab data.

I would store data on server anyway. If push fails - you can retry it. No need to reinvent wheel. Most issues/problems already solved in C2DM

Comment: Thank you for the link, but what if I need to run my application on Android starting from version 1.6. As far as I understood C2DM support added only in 2.2 version...

Comment: Without push - you can't achieve "smoothly and quickly" requirement. You can write data to server with device A but then device B have to periodically pull for update. Doing it often will kill battery right there. And from what I know you can't rely on connection between device and server. IP may change, wireless going on and off, etc.

Comment: Yeap, I also know this, that's why I asked the question. But I seriously need the solution for all versions started from 1.6. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, you may decide to spend money on SMS service. This way server will SMS device B and you can intercept this with your code.

Comment: Thank you for the last useful answer, I will definitely follow your advice.